# Comparison of non unique data in 2 dataframes

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes having columns in which data is getting repeated so there is no column we can consider as primary key on the basis of which we can merge 2 files. So I created a unique id column and iterated over it. My problem statement is i need to separate out the data if it matches in both the dataframes then in one DF and if it is present in one sheet then different DF and if in another then different DF.

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import zip_longest
    import xlrd
    def main():
        file1_left_only()
        file1_both()
        file1_right()
        file2_left_only()
        file2_both()
        file2_right()
        
    
    def joining_file1_outer_join(): 
        xls1 = pd.ExcelFile('xlsx1')
        df1 = pd.read_excel(xls1, 'All Feeds Sept')
        df1["ID"]=df1["ID"].astype(str)
        df1["Batch ID"]=df1["Batch ID"].astype(str)
        df1["Index"]=df1["Index"].astype(str)
        df1["Gift Date"]=df1["Gift Date"].astype(str)
        df1["Gift Amount"]=df1["Gift Amount"].astype(str)
        df1["Unique_ID"] = np.random.randint(len(df1))
        
        #df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
      #print(df1)
        xls2 = pd.ExcelFile('xlsx2')
        df2 = pd.read_excel(xls2,'Report Data')
        df2["ID"]=df2["ID"].astype(str)
        df2["Batch ID"]=df2["Batch ID"].astype(str)
        df2["Index"]=df2["Index"].astype(str)
        df2["Gift Date"]=df2["Gift Date"].astype(str)
        df2["Gift Amount"]=df2["Gift Amount"].astype(str)
        df2["Unique_ID"] = np.random.randint(len(df2))
        
        df1_sheet1 = xlrd.open_workbook('xlsx1')
        df2_sheet2 = xlrd.open_workbook('xlsx2')
         
        sheet1 = df1_sheet1.sheet_by_index(0)
        sheet2= df2_sheet2.sheet_by_index(0)
        new_empty_frame = []
        for i,rowwise_sheet1 in enumerate(range(sheet1.nrows)):
            row_df1_sheet1= sheet1.row_values(rowwise_sheet1)
            for rowwise_sheet2 in ((range(sheet2.nrows))):
                row_df2_sheet2 = sheet2.row_values(rowwise_sheet2)
                if row_df1_sheet1[19] == row_df2_sheet2[17]:
                    if row_df1_sheet1[8] == row_df2_sheet2[0]:
                        if row_df1_sheet1[17] == row_df2_sheet2[14]:
                            if row_df1_sheet1[2] == row_df2_sheet2[10]:
                                if row_df1_sheet1[18] == row_df2_sheet2[3]:
                                    if row_df1_sheet1[17] == row_df2_sheet2[2]:
                                       new_df_file=new_empty_frame.append(row_df1_sheet1)
                                       df_new_file = new_df_file.to_excel('xlsxtestfile')
    def file1_left_only():
        joining_file1_outer_join()
        final_file1 = pd.read_excel('xlsx1')
        final_file1['_merge'].to_string()
    #print(type(final_file1['merge']))
    #for i in str(final_file1['merge']):
    #if final_file1['merge'] == 'left_only':
        left_only_sheet = (final_file1['_merge'] == 'left_only')
            #print(left_only_sheet)
        final_file_left = final_file1[left_only_sheet]
        final_file_left.to_excel('only0919progressreport.xlsx')
    def file1_both():
        final_file1 = pd.read_excel('xlsx1')
        final_file1['_merge'].to_string()
    #elif final_file1['merge'] == 'both':
        df_both0919andcombinedreport = (final_file1['_merge'] == 'both')
        final_file1_both = final_file1[df_both0919andcombinedreport]
        final_file1_both.to_excel('both0919andcombinedreport.xlsx')
    #elif final_file1['merge'] == 'right_only':
    def file1_right():
        final_file1 = pd.read_excel('xlsx1')
        final_file1['_merge'].to_string()
        df_right_only_data = (final_file1['_merge'] == 'right_only')
        final_file1_right_only = final_file1[df_right_only_data]
        final_file1_right_only.to_excel('marysreportonly.xlsx')
         
    def joining_file2_outer_join():
        xls3 = pd.ExcelFile('xlsx1')
        df3 = pd.read_excel(xls3, 'Report Data')
        df3["ID"]=df3["ID"].astype(str)
        df3["Batch ID"]=df3["Batch ID"].astype(str)
        df3["Index"]=df3["Index"].astype(str)
        df3["Gift Date"]=df3["Gift Date"].astype(str)
        df3["Gift Amount"]=df3["Gift Amount"].astype(str)
        df3["Unique_ID"] = np.random.sample(len(df3))
    # print(df3)
        xls4 = pd.ExcelFile('xlsx2')
        df4 = pd.read_excel(xls4,'All Feeds Sept')
        df4["ID"]=df4["ID"].astype(str)
        df4["Batch ID"]=df4["Batch ID"].astype(str)
        df4["Index"]=df4["Index"].astype(str)
        df4["Gift Date"]=df4["Gift Date"].astype(str)
        df4["Gift Amount"]=df4["Gift Amount"].astype(str)
        df4["Unique_ID"] = np.random.sample(len(df4))
        #if ((df3['ID'] == df4['ID']) and (df3['Batch ID'] == df4['Batch ID']) and (df3['Gift Date'] == df4['Gift Date']) and (df3['Index'] == df4['Index']) and (df3[' Gift Amount'] == df4['Gift Amount'])):
    # print(df4)
        merge_results2 = pd.merge(df3,df4,on=['Unique_ID','ID','Batch ID','Index','Gift Date','Index','Gift Amount'], how='outer', indicator=True)
    # print(merge_results2)
        df_new_file2 = merge_results2.to_excel('giftrecon_2nd.xlsx')
        
    def file2_left_only():
        joining_file2_outer_join()
        final_file2 = pd.read_excel('file1')
        final_file2['_merge'].to_string()
        left_only_sheet2 = (final_file2['_merge'] == 'left_only')
            #print(left_only_sheet)
        final_file2_left = final_file2[left_only_sheet2]
        final_file2_left.to_excel('onlymarysrecords.xlsx')
        
    def file2_both():
        final_file2 = pd.read_excel('file2')
        final_file2['_merge'].to_string()
    #elif final_file1['merge'] == 'both':
        df_both0919andcombinedreport2 = (final_file2['_merge'] == 'both')
        final_file2_both = final_file2[df_both0919andcombinedreport2]
        final_file2_both.to_excel('both0919andcombinedreport2.xlsx')
    
    def file2_right():
        final_file2 = pd.read_excel('file3')
        final_file2['_merge'].to_string()
        df_right_only_data2 = (final_file2['_merge'] == 'right_only')
        final_file2_right_only = final_file2[df_right_only_data2]
        final_file2_right_only.to_excel('0919reportonly.xlsx')
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you add minimal example?

Comment: If i understood correctly, you want a new dataframe with all rows that are present in both df1 and df2 and remove these rows from df1 and df2?

Comment: Yes I want these rows in a new dataframe and after removing these rows from df1 and df2 we are left with uncommon data that I will pull out in separate sheet.